# Calculate rowwise maximum from columns that have changing names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following objects:

```
s1 = "1_1_1_1_1"
s2 = "2_1_1_1_1"
s3 = "3_1_1_1_1"
```

Please note that the value of s1, s2, s3 can change in another example.

I then have the follwoing data frame:

```
set.seed(666)
df = data.frame(draw = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                resp = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                "1_1_1_1_1" = runif(12),
                "2_1_1_1_1" = runif(12),
                "3_1_1_1_1" = runif(12)).
```

Please note that the column names of may data frame will change based on the values of s1,s2,s3.

I now want to achieve the following:

1. I want to find out which of last three columns in `df` has the highest value and store it as a value in a new column (values are supposed to be either of 1,2 or 3, depending on if the highest value is the first, second or third of these variables).
2. Now that I know which value is the highest **per row**, I want to group/summarize the result by the column `resp` and count how often my max value is 1, 2 or 3.

So the outcome from 1. should be:

```
draw    resp    1_1_1_1_1    2_1_1_1_1    3_1_1_1_1    max
1       1       0.774        0.095        0.806        3
2       1       0.197        0.142        0.266        3
...
```

And the outcome from 2. is supposed to be:

```
resp    first_max    second_max    third_max
1       1            1             2
2       2            1             1
3       1            2             1
```

My problem is that tidyverse's rowwise function is deprecated and that I don't know how I can dynamically address columns in a tidyverse pipe by column names which a re stored externally (here in s1, s2, s3). One last note: I might be overcomplicating things by trying to go by the column names, when, in fact, the positions of the columns that I'm interested in are always at column position 3:5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to get what you want. For a sligthly different format, you can use `count` rather than `table` but this matches your expected output. Hope this helps!!

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(max_val = max.col(select(., starts_with("X")))) %>%
  select(resp, max_val) %>%
  table()

    max_val
resp 1 2 3
   1 1 1 2
   2 2 1 1
   3 1 2 1
```

Or, you could do this:

```
df %>%
  mutate(max_val = max.col(.[3:5])) %>%
  count(resp, max_val) %>%
  mutate(max_val = paste0("max_", max_val)) %>%
  spread(value = n, key = max_val)

   resp max_1 max_2 max_3
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     2
2     2     2     1     1
3     3     1     2     1
```

Comment: Assuming the OP may want to select columns with some pattern in their names, it could be useful to include `max.col(select(., starts_with("X")))`.

Comment: I quickly tried the first solution and it works. Thanks! I changed the `select ` and `table()` part to a combination of `groupy_by` and `summarise` commands so that I can easily store the results and continue working with them. The main function I was missing and unable to find was the `max.col` function.

Comment: Great point @tmfmnk. Much more flexible--just updated! Also, glad it worked for you, deschen!

Comment: The second solution is even better, because it is agnostic to the number of columns and automatically creates as much columns as I have as input (e.g. 6 columns instead of the 3 from teh example).

Comment: @Andrew Any idea on another `max.col` like function? It appears, this function has a maximum tolerance of 1e-5, which in my case is not enough, e.g. when comparing 0.3762792 and 0.3762818, the max.col function randomly returns either the first or the second value as the highest, where in this case it shoudl clearly be the second.

Comment: @deschen, wow, that's a low tolerance. If you check out `?max.col` you will see the `apply` equivalent that uses `which.max` to select the first max (in case there is a tie). But, the tolerance of `which.max` should be higher. Otherwise I will have to think more about a more efficient solution.

Comment: The suggested alternative indeed leads to more consistent results. However, I can't tell if that's because `which.max` has a higher tolerance than max.col (wasn't able to find anything informative on that matter) or if it's just because the suggested alternative which.max always returns the _first_ maximum.

Comment: Well, I just raised this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57393262/whats-the-tolerance-of-the-which-max-function-in-r and it appears that which.max indeed has a higher tolerance.

Comment: Very interesting--I will dig a bit more into this. It is just odd that it is so low.

Answer (score 1):

calculate max using `pmap`(row-wise iteration)

```r
max_cols <- pmap_dbl(unname(df),function(x,y,...){
    vals <- unlist(list(...))
    return(which(vals == max(vals)))
})


result <- df %>% add_column(max = max_cols)
```

```r
> result
   draw resp X1_1_1_1_1 X2_1_1_1_1  X3_1_1_1_1 max
1     1    1  0.4551478 0.70061232 0.618439890   2
2     2    1  0.3667764 0.26670969 0.024742605   1
3     3    1  0.6806912 0.03233215 0.004014758   1
4     4    1  0.9117449 0.42926492 0.885247456   1
5     1    2  0.1886954 0.34189707 0.985054492   3
6     2    2  0.5569398 0.78043504 0.100714130   2
7     3    2  0.9791164 0.92823982 0.676584495   1
8     4    2  0.9174654 0.74627116 0.485582287   1
9     1    3  0.3681890 0.69622331 0.672346875   2
10    2    3  0.5510356 0.99651637 0.482430518   2
11    3    3  0.4283281 0.12832611 0.018095649   1
12    4    3  0.6168436 0.64381995 0.655178701   3
```

Reshape the data frame.

```r
reshape2::dcast(result,resp~max,fun.aggregate = length,value.var = "max")
```

```r
  resp 1 2 3
1    1 1 1 2
2    2 2 1 1
3    3 1 2 1
```