# What's the tolerance of the which.max function in R?

Tags: r, precision

Based on a problem I discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57364028/2725773 I'm wondering what's the tolerance/precision of the `which.max` function in R.

Specifically, the alternative `max.col` function has a tolerance of 1e-5, which means that 0.12345 is the same for it as 0.12346.

The help page for max.col suggests an alternative, namely using `unname(apply(m, 1, which.max))`, which brings me to the questions what's the tolerance of `which.max`?

Comment: ADAIK, there is no tolerance except floating point precision. `max.col` also has a *relative* tolerance not an absolute tolerance as you assume.

Comment: E.g., `max.col(cbind(0.12345, 0.12346))` will never return `1`.

Comment: @Roland, can you explain more. I am digging a bit more into it and it seems like there is only an issue when the `ties.method = random`. I.e., (`max.col(data.frame(a = rep(.123456, 5), b = rep(.123457, 5)), ties.method = "random")` vs `max.col(data.frame(a = rep(.123456, 5), b = rep(.123457, 5)), ties.method = "first")`). I can open a new question if it is sufficiently odd.

Comment: What is odd there? 1e-5 * .123457 = 1.23457e-06 > .123457 - .123456 = 1e-6 And the documentation is clear on this only applying to random breaking of ties (the default).

Comment: I am not tracking. When `ties.method = "random"` it jumps between the two columns. When `ties.method = "first"` or `"last"` it consistently selects the correct column. That seems buggy to me. What am I not understanding (genuinely asking, not trying to be contentious)? So, is the tolerance low for "random" and more robust for "first" and "last"?

Comment: Thanks @Roland for clarifying. It is true that the problem only occurs with `ties.method = "random"` and in that the behaviour is expected. However, I'm now wondering why there is such a low relative tolerance. Is it performance-related? Just FYI, the numbers I originally wanted to compare with max.col were 0.3762792 and 0.3762818.

Comment: @Roland, just saw the edit to your comment. To me, it is odd to have the relative tolerance so low on the default, but the function makes more sense. Not buggy at all. Cheers!!

Comment: It can be surprisingly difficult to find a good default tolerance for comparison of floating point numbers ... `all.equal` uses `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)` as default but I suspect that `max.col` has a fixed tolerance for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Fascinating question. I do not know the precise answer. But it's possible to test some *very* small numbers to see what happens..

```r
# the fourth element is the max
c(1,2,3,4,2) %>% which.max
# [1] 4

vec <- c(1,2,3,4,2)

# how tiny can the numbers become before which.max cannot tell the difference between them?
for(i in 1:30) {

  vec <- vec / (10 ^ i)
  max_num <- vec %>% which.max 
  print(vec)
  print(max_num)

}
```

It looks like the smallest these numbers can get to is `1e-300 2e-300 3e-300 4e-300 2e-300` (on the next iteration, `which.max` cannot tell the difference)

Comment: Thanks, simple idea to test it empirically. And it indeed appears that which.max has a higher tolerance (which is good).